# Changing Coordinate axes type in Paraview

Tags: paraview

How to change in Paraview, the co-ordinate axes from default to left-handed co-ordinates from [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3fU6.png) to [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09AnW.png)

I am reading in a vtk file written in legacy format for rectilinear grid

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ParaView does not support left-handed coordinates. The best you can do is convert your left handed coordinates to right-handed coordinates to make them displayed correctly. The easiest way to do so is probably to use the Transform filter and scale by -1 along one axis.

Unfortunately, you cannot change the labels of the orientation axes (in the lower right corner) to be labeled as left-handed. However, if you are using the Axes Grid, you can changes the labels of that to indicate left-handed coordinates.